# syntax error - use if eval() from Grid to call Javascript function

Tags: c#, asp.net

can some one please tell me where is the mistake from my side, to call this function.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkImageVideo" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowTaskAttachmentPopup('<%# Eval("AttachmentFileName") %>','<%#Eval ("AttachmentFilePath") %>','Task Attachment'); return false;">
                                                               </asp:LinkButton>
```

if i put the function with static values (avoid eval inside grid) it works fine.

purpose: call javascript function on row link of grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
OnClientClick="ShowTaskAttachmentPopup('<%# Eval("AttachmentFileName") %>','<%#Eval ("AttachmentFilePath") %>','Task Attachment'); return false;"
```

To:

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("ShowTaskAttachmentPopup('{0}','{1}'); return false;", Eval("AttachmentFileName"), Eval("AttachmentFilePath")) %>'
```

Comment: Curt, mine is also right, however your's not working for me. Anyway, thanks for help and i like to mark as answer to get help from this way for someone. I done the code from codebehind and it is working